# PHP Form: required field content

Tags: php, forms, required

I am working on a simple PHP form for a newsletter sign up, with fields based on this format:

```
  $formArray['e'] = array(
    'name'    => __('Email', 'esu_lang'),
    'validate'=> 'esu-required-email',
    'id'      => 'email',
    'class'   => 'esu-input',
    'type'    => 'text');
```

In order to avoid spam, I would like to add a field with the question "Which year are we now?", so that only real people can write "2015". Technically, I would thus like to require a specific content ("2015") for a field. Is this possible do to this without Javascript?

I have been looking for this on the Internet, but didn't find anything.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can process the form and check the value, and redirect back to the site containing the form and remembering the error in a session or so, but you can't do it _dynamically_ without JavaScript. Although you could possibly use the html5 pattern attribute to match an exact value but it's usually used for a regular expression pattern but you can try to make it match exactly one result (i.e. starting with a 2, continuing with a 0, continuing with a 1 and ending with a 5).

Comment: jQuery rather than PHP would be a better bet, this could be applied pre-submission.

Comment: Thank you @Jonast92, I will try the pattern attribute...

Comment: Actually, the pattern attribute is not supported by older versions of IE nor Safari, so I'll better avoid that...

Comment: @Jonas Then you better use JavaScript to detect changes of that input and determine whether the form should be disabled or not, but then again the JavaScript can simply be turned off so you better check it _client side_ (listener, check value, disable/enable form) **and** _server side_ (check processed value, redirect and display an error message kept in a session for display).

Answer (score 0):

you can write your question as **Placeholder** of input field.

Comment: And how does that help OP?

Comment: Sorry but i do not understand meaning of your **OP**. But as i am understanding your question, you just want to validate the answer without javascript. You can use pattern to validate. May be like this  **<form>
<input type="text" name="validate" placeholder="Which year are we now?" pattern="(<?php echo date('Y')?>)" title="Which year are we now?" required>
<input type="submit" />
</form>** @Jonast92

Answer (score 0):

Insert a input element in the HTML form and let the user enter the current year. In PHP, after you get the POST request, compare the entered value to PHPs year.

Something like this:

HTML:

```
<form method='post' action='handle.php'>
  <!-- insert the remaining needed inputs -->
  <input type='text' name='verify_human'>
</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
  $verify_human = $_POST['verify_human'];

  if ( $verify_human == date("Y", time()) ) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use array validation with data("Y") function equivalent to user entered input.